# No displaying the right content from tab content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't display the content of "lagers": When I press the "lagers" button, it shows the content of "anglo-American". What am I doing wrong?

Here's a codepen with my code: https://codepen.io/denxero/pen/ExRRqpR

```js
function showTab(beerName) {
  let i, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontents");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  document.getElementById(beerName).style.display = "grid";
}

const header = document.querySelector(".header");
const links = header.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    const current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    currentSlide(1);
  });
}
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}
function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontents");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "grid";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.dots .dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;

  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.dot.active {
  background-color: black;
}
.dot:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="header overall-layout">
  <button class="tablink" onclick="showTab('lagers')">Lagers</button>
  <button class="tablink active" onclick="showTab('anglo')">Anglo-American Ales</button>
  <button class="tablink">Belgian-Style Ales</button>
  <button class="tablink">Stout and Porter</button>
  <button class="tablink">Sour Beer</button>
  <button class="tablink">Wheat Beer</button>
  <button class="tablink">Other Styles</button>
</section>
<section class="details-beers overall-layout" id="details-beers">
  <!-- Anglo-American -->
  <div class="tabcontent tabcontents fade" id="anglo">
    <div class="title">
      <h4>new</h4>
      <h4>england</h4>
      <h4>i.p.a.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos1">
       <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/ultra violence.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos2">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/koelship.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos3">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/kveik.png" alt="bacchus" />
    </div>
    <div class="beer-text">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/text.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabcontent tabcontents fade">
    <div class="title">
      <h4>black</h4>
      <h4>i.p.a.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos1">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/koelship.png" alt="bacchus" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos2">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/koelship.png" alt="bacchus" />
    </div>
    <div class="beer-text">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/text.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- lagers -->
  <div class="tabcontent tabcontents fade" id="lagers">
    <div class="title">
      <h4>marzen</h4>
      <h4>oktoberfest</h4>
      <h4>beer</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-photos1">
      <img src="./Photos/modern times.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="beer-text">
      <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/text.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabcontent tabcontents fade" id="lagers">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>apri</h4>
    <h4>oktoberfest</h4>
    <h4>beer</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-photos1">
    <img src="./Photos/modern times.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="beer-text">
    <img src="./Photos/new england ipa/text.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dots" id="slide-control">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
```

For brevity I excluded button functionality for all except for the "lagers" and "anglo-american" buttons.

Comment: first of all, you have multiple IDs with name "lagers" in your html code. ID must always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the display grid inside a setTimeout it should work, something like this (instead of line 9 of your js):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById(beerName).style.display = "grid";
}
```

But maybe a better way to do it would be to get all tabs when the pages loads into a "tabs" variable. Then when the button is clicked you go through the tabs and see if it is the correct one or not and add / remove the stlyes, maybe something like this:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let currentTab = 'tab-one';

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});

function handleButtonClick(event) {
  currentTab = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('target-tab');
  updateTabsUI();
}

function updateTabsUI() {
  tabs.forEach((tab) => {
    tab.getAttribute('id') === currentTab ?
      tab.classList.add('tab--visible') :
      tab.classList.remove('tab--visible');
  })
}

updateTabsUI();
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.tab--visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" target-tab="tab-one">Tab One</button>
<button class="button" target-tab="tab-two">Tab Two</button>
<button class="button" target-tab="tab-three">Tab Three</button>

<div class="tab" id="tab-one">
  <p>This is the tab ONE</p>
</div>

<div class="tab" id="tab-two">
  <p>This is the tab TWO</p>
</div>

<div class="tab" id="tab-three">
  <p>This is the tab THREE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: brother it does not work..the lager button has no functionality at all...

Comment: @argyris what do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any errors? What have you changed in your code? My example should be working ok, have you tried refactoring your code to use that kind of approach (which would fix your problem and improve performance)

Comment: your example works perfectly but in my code the lager button has no functionality..i inspect it and i see that never reads tab-two..

Comment: @argyris i would suggest that you rewrite your code to make it more readable and easier to work with. You could also improve performance and accessibility.
Maybe you could also look into the `<details>` Element, which you can easily style like a tab (without need JS, or almost no JS)

Comment: if i comment out the function showSlides(n) the tabs work fine..I believe must change this function but i m stuck..I try several options none of them work..